# TypeScript 'var' is undefined error

Tags: undefined, typescript

I built a console app to find all the *.ts files in my project and then compile them using tsc.exe.

Everything was working fine, but as I converted my JavaScript files to TypeScript, I eventually ran into the following error:

ytsc.js(21053, 17) Microsoft JScipt runtime error: 'window' is undefined

Each time this happened when I was trying to extend window:

```
window['prop'] = "something";
```

I tested the code until I found the answer, which had little to do with my code...

Answer (score 2):

The fault was my build tool.

I had declared the -e (execute) command line option when calling tsc.exe:
I did this because I thought I might add some automated testing code in the modules.

The cause for the error:
Most of my code is in functions.
However, there were a few places that I wanted to extend 'window' (for example if a built in function is missing from an old browser, I was shimming those calls). The code to shim the window object was running as the file loaded:

```
if (window.fun == null) {
    window.fun = function(){...};
}
```

Anyway, because of the -e option, the tsc.exe was attempting to run the code (outside of a browser environment). This caused the above error.